# lambda if with list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I try to print from a list, only the organs that match the condition (divided by 2) with the help of a Lambda and something here does not work:

```
list = list(range(0, 50))
[(lambda x: print(x) if(x % 2 == 0)(x(l)) for l in list]
```

Comment: Take the lambda out of the list comprehension and store it in a variable and then call it inside your list comprehension

Comment: There is a lot more going on here than just using the `lambda`. In general, you should use `lambda` when you actually want to use the value that comes from evaluating the expression - don't use it to `print`. Anyway, I don't understand *why* you want to write code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a lambda for this task, you can just use a list comprehension to generate the sub-list of elements matching the condition:

```
l = list(range(0, 50))
print([x for x in l if x % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

check it

```py
x = [i for i in range(50) if not i %2]
```

Comment: BTW, don't use built-in list as a var

Comment: try this x[1::2]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `lambda` for this. You can do this way:

```
list = list(range(50))
[i for i in list if i%2==0]
```